# Accessing data of div with class 'note-editable ' of summer-note editor div

Tags: javascript, html

I want to access the text written in `summer-note` editor to save it into the database.

I am using summer note for my blog site, but I am not able to access the data of the div with class name `note-editable`..

This is the code of the div I'd like to access:

```
<div class="note-editable" contenteditable="true" style="height: 510px;">
    hi...Write an amazing Post....
</div>
```

anyone knows how to achieve it ..thanks in advance....

Comment: This is very simple thing, but have you tried ? write some code here and we will give you answer

Comment: Yes I tried by giving the id to div and then ...accessing it with ajax ...but that didn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just grab the element and then the text inside of it.

Like this:

```js
var content = document.getElementsByClassName('note-editable')[0];

console.log(content.innerHTML)
```

```html
<div class="note-editable" contenteditable="true" style="height: 510px;">hi...Write an amazing Post....</div>
```

Comment: Avoid using `.innerHTML` to get text content, `.innerText` is more appropriate in this case, you can see its limitations on my post.

Answer (score 3):

Just see what the developers have set in place for this task: (from summernote.org):

> get & set Code
>
> Get the HTML contents of the first summernote in the set of matched
>   elements.
>
> `var sHTML = $('.summernote').code();`
>
> Get the HTML content of the second summernote with jQuery eq.
>
> `var sHTML = $('.summernote').eq(1).code();`
>
> A string of HTML to set as the content of each matched element.
>
> `$('.summernote').code(sHTML);`
>
> for more detail api: deep dive with api

What is wrong with this code? What you can obtain?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use **[innerText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533899(v=vs.85).aspx)** or **[.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)** properties to get the text inside your div:

```js
var text = document.getElementsByClassName('note-editable')[0].innerText;

alert(text);
```

```html
<div class="note-editable" contenteditable="true" style="height: 510px;">Hi...Write an amazing Post....</div>
```

**Note:**

Avoid using `innerHTML` because it will return the sub-elements HTML code also and referring to the **[innerHTML documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)**:

> If a `<div>`, `<span>`, or `<noembed>` node has a child text node that includes the characters (&), (<), or (>), innerHTML returns these characters as &amp, &lt and &gt respectively. Use Node.textContent to get a correct copy of these text nodes' contents.